# Rewrite react functional component in vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, components, jsx

I'm having a hard time understanding how the functional component in React through es6 gets the props as an argument by placing it in an object. Is this part of es6's feature? Or is it part of React to magically pull the props through as an argument without having to refer to `this.props...`? If someone can rewrite the below component in vanilla js for me with a function (not React.createElement as Babel repl does), that would be very helpful.

```
const Repos = ({repos}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3> User Repos </h3>
      <ul className="list-group">
        {repos.map((repo, index) => {
          return (
            <li className="list-group-item" key={repo.name}>
              <h4><a href={repo.html_url}>{repo.name}</a></h4>
              <p>{repo.description}</p>
            </li>
          )
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a destructuring assignment and part of the ES2015 spec. `Repos` is a function that expects an `Object`. When `Repos` is called it evaluates the destructuring pattern and assigns the result to its single argument:

```js
const Repos = ({repos}) => {
  return repos;
}

const props = {repos: [1,2,3]};
const foo = {bar: "baz"};

console.log(Repos(props));
console.log(Repos(foo));
```

The name of the property (`repos`) and the name of the argument that is  actually passed to `Repos` are the same, because the given destructuring pattern doesn't define a different one (in fact `({repos})` is shorthand for `({repos:repos})`). However, a different name makes it clearer what is happening under the hood:

```js
const Repos = ({repos:arg}) => {
  return arg;
}

const props = {repos: [1,2,3]};

console.log(Repos(props));
```

Please note that this has nothing to do with default parameters.

Comment: great explanation! is the argument always implicitly returned if you don't do anything with it? so usually when this is working with react and a functional component gets multiple props, does es6 destructure each one individually? so if you have `props = {foo:"foo", bar:"bar"}` React will pass that into a component for you as an argument and then when you declare `const = function ({foo, bar}) {...}` and call it later, es6 will know the argument obj is referring to props and automatically destructure it for you to use in your function?

Comment: Ya, you can destructure several properties, if that is your question. But you can't define a destructuring pattern dynamically that is, you always have to know at implementation time, which properties you want.

Answer (score 2):

It's using [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and yes it's part of the standard.

What it is basically doing is the equivalent of saying

```
const repos = props.repos;
```

Which you would do if you had `props` as a parameter

```
const Repos = (props) => {
  const repos = props.repos;
  return (
    <div>
      (...)
    </div>
  )
}
```

In ES3 you would also have to spell out the function keyword and use `var` instead of `const`.

```
var Repos = function(props) {
  var repos = props.repos;
  return (
    <div>
      (...)
    </div>
  )
}
```

So the only React-magic going on is the use of JSX to inline markup within the code.

Comment: so it es6 does the destructuring INSIDE the parameter? I think that was what was throwing me off - because i'm used to seeing destructuring happening in the body of a function. essentially, this means `const Repos = (var repos = props.repos) => { //now you have access to repos as you normally would any argument
  return (
    <div>
      (...)
    </div>
  )
}`

Comment: Yes. that's more or less what is happening.

Comment: I actually wasn't aware you can do assignments in the parameter list but `const f = (bar = 'zot') => console.log(bar); f();` runs in the console so I guess you can.

Comment: That is also a new feature in ES2015 known as [default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) which is useful for setting initial values to your parameters.

Comment: @stackjlei The destructuring pattern is evaluated when `Repos` is called and the result is assigned to `Repos`'s argument list. See my answer.

Comment: @saadq Yeah, I realized that after leaving the office but I was on my phone and don't have the app and it would have been too late to edit the comment anyway. Thanks for clarifying it in the meantime :)